# Necessary to close web request stream?

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest

Which way is preferrable?

A:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
reqStream.Close();
```

B:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Option C instead:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

But yes, I *would* close the request stream. It's *possible* that it's not absolutely required, but I wouldn't like to assume that - and in particular, unless you have good reason to believe it's *not* required (such as documentation), the implementation could change over time and break "lazy" code later.

If you find yourself doing this often, you could always write a utility method (possibly even as an extension method):

```
public static void WriteRequestData(this WebRequest request, byte[] data)
{
    using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Then just call it as:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.WriteRequestData(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party but this question is still relevant. I'd like to add:
[MSDN Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also demonstrate/suggest closing the stream when writing is complete.

```
Stream newStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ();
newStream.Write (byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
Console.WriteLine ("The value of 'ContentLength' property after sending the data is {0}", myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength);
// Close the Stream object.
newStream.Close ();
```

I like @Jon's example and follow a similar pattern.